# Use of android lockscreen in an application for security purposes

Tags: android, lockscreen

I am new to android and I am trying to make a security based app in which I want create android lock screen which appears after clicking an item of list view.
Am I suppose to use the same lock screen code as available and make some changes?
I tried to search for my problem but couldn't find anything.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html